# cannot get option values after updating option

Tags: jquery, html

This code works fine:

```
$("#day option").click(function () {
    daySelected = $("#day select").val();
});
```

But after this function:

```
$("#month option").click(function () {
    $("#day select").html("<option value='default'>Day</option>");
    for (var i = 1; i <= daysNum; i++) {
        $("#day select").append("<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>");
    }
    if (parseInt(daySelected) > daysNum) {
        $("#day select").val(String(daysNum));
    } else {
        $("#day select").val(daySelected);
    }
});
```

my `daySelected` variable won't change its value anymore when I click `$("#day option")`.

Answer (score 1):

I think because `jQuery click` function is used for already exists element.
So when you clear and recreate `option` element, `click event` not attach to it.
I guess you can use `on` function like this.

```
$("#day").on('click', 'option', function () {
    daySelected = $("#day select").val();
});
```

Hope this help.